# Jenkinsfile Post-Failure step triggering for old builds

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins build where I send a slack notification if the build fails. It works correctly when the current build fails, but it will also run this failure block for older builds at the same time.

For example, if the old build failed and the new build passed, you will get 1 slack message for the old build, while if both fail or both pass you will get 2 slack messages or no slack messages. The old builds are always 283 builds back from the current.

Here is the current failure block

```
failure {
    script {
            if (((env.BUILD_NUMBER as Integer) > 1450 && env.BRANCH_NAME == 'develop') || ((env.BUILD_NUMBER as Integer) > 150 || env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master')) {
                sh "curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{${KEY}: ${FAILURE_MESSAGE}}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/blah/blah/blah"
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to add the conditional to make sure that we only send notifications for current builds, but it doesn't seem to work. Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: i think your issue is in the using of the if condition, u are using Or || . so make sure you are doing the condition right cuz may be you need && but you are mistaken. Just double check your condition , everything else seems fine

Comment: @mbn217damn your right, can't beleive I missed that. Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes. Thanks!